# Can Objects with Zero Built-in Properties Exist in Python?

Tags: python, object, types

From [the W3Schools sandbox](https://www.w3schools.com/python/trypython.asp?filename=demo_ref_object), it appears that even creating empty objects leaves a good many of built-in methods.

I'm interested in creating a distinct data class that only has certain built-in methods in it, and I'm wondering if that's even possible in pure Python.

Second, is there any real performance benefit to gain if it is possible and I use a lot of these distinct objects in a program?

Comment: It's not. All classes inherit from `object`, so you can't get anything simpler.

Comment: In pure Python, you can't do it.  A C extension like `numpy` can have data elements that aren't objects until you use Python statements to interact with them.

Comment: You understand, instances of classes **do not contain methods**. suppose you have a class `class Foo: pass`, then `foo = Foo()`, when you do `print(vars(foo))` it is empty. Now, suppose you use `foo.__eq__`, a method that all instances have, well, it looks it up in the instance namespace (actually, this is skipped usually because it is a "special method") doesn't find it, checks `vars(Foo)`, doesn't find it, then finally finds it in `object`.

Comment: If you *do* want to save space on instances, then use `__slots__`, which prevents every instances from carrying around it's own `dict`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga This is one thing I learned in reading about `__slots__` and `__weakref__`, though the dictionary's getting and setting was something I wanted from the object.